# I want to create a laravel job that send sms messages to my defined defaulters query rather than using the user model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, sms-gateway

see the code trying to use the user model

```php
class SendBirthdayMessage implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $user;
    private $twilioClient;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     * @param User $user: A single user instance whose birthday is current date.
     * @throws ConfigurationException
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $sid = config('services.twilio.account_sid');
        $token = config('services.twilio.auth_token');
        $this->twilioClient = new Client($sid, $token);
    }
```

then see what i am trying to implement

```php
class SendDefaulterMessage implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    
    private $twilioClient;
    private  $defaulters = DB::table('forrent')
    ->join('landlord','forrent.LandLordID','=','landlord.LandLordID')
    ->join('tenant','forrent.AccountNo','=','tenant.AccountNo')
    ->join('property','tenant.PropertyID','=','property.PropertyID')
    ->select(DB::raw("CONCAT(landlord.Title,' ',landlord.OtherNames,' ',landlord.Surname) as Lfullname"),DB::raw("CONCAT(tenant.Title,' ',tenant.OtherNames,' ',tenant.Surname) as Tfullname"),'tenant.RegDate as RegDate', 'tenant.AccountNo as Accno','tenant.Rent as Rent', 'tenant.NoOfProperty as NoOfProperty','tenant.Address as Address','tenant.Phone as Phone','forrent.LastPeriod as LastPeriod','forrent.LPDate as Lp', 'property.Property as Property','property.Description as Description')
    ->get();

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    
    public function __construct($defaulters)
    {
        $this->defaulters = $defaulters;
        $sid = config('services.twilio.account_sid');
        $token = config('services.twilio.auth_token');
        $this->twilioClient = new Client($sid, $token);
    }
```

i get an error saying "Constant expression contains invalid operations". then i found out the issue as a result of the private defaulters variable.
please does anybody know a way round this.

Comment: _please does anybody know a way round this._ Yes. Write valid PHP. You can’t put an expression like that as the value of a class property.

Comment: If you're not passing in defaulters when instantiating the job, you can define it in your constructor instead

Comment: Please still learning. Tell me the correct sequence I should follow please

Comment: @OskarMikael thank you I just did that it worked. Still trying to understand the concepts

Comment: @OskarMikael please when I tried to run the code got an error saying undefined property saying I can’t access the attribute Tfullname in the query. Accessors don’t work with query builders please what other solutions can I try

Comment: Youll have to post more code, on what and how you're trying to query